# Problem with reference using VS Code (Classes)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with this program or, better said... with this idle, which is not compiling correctly when running the program. I had run it in others compilers, like Repl. It and it works perfectly.

File: main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include "Dumbbell.hpp"
//


int main(){

    Dumbbell d1,d2;
    double val1, val2;

    cout << "Enter two values, please: " << endl;
    cin >> val1 >> val2;

    d1.setWeight(val1);
    d2.setWeight(val2);
    
    
    cout << "Dumbbell #1: " << d1.getWeight() << " lbs" << endl;
    cout << "Dumbbell #2: " << d2.getWeight() << " lbs" << endl;

    



    return 0;
}
```

File: Dumbbell.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef _Dumbbell_H_
#define _Dumbbell_H_

class Dumbbell {
    private:
        double weight;
    public:
        Dumbbell ();
        Dumbbell (float w);
        double getWeight ();
        void setWeight (double w);
        ~Dumbbell ();
};

#endif //_Dumbbell_H_
```

File: Dumbbell.cpp

```
#include "Dumbbell.hpp"

Dumbbell::Dumbbell () { // Default Constructor  
    weight = -1;
}
Dumbbell::Dumbbell (float w) {        // Non-Default Constructor
    weight = w;
}
Dumbbell::~Dumbbell() {   
    cout << "From the Destructor!" << endl;
}
void Dumbbell::setWeight(double w) {
    this -> weight = w;
}
double Dumbbell::getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

But in VS Code, it shows me a message when I execute main...

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::Dumbbell()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::Dumbbell()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::setWeight(double)'        
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::setWeight(double)'        
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::getWeight()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::getWeight()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::~Dumbbell()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::~Dumbbell()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::~Dumbbell()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\giuma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPFLsZY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to `Dumbbell::~Dumbbell()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Most likely you didn't edit the correct file to tell VSC that it needs to compile and link Dumbbell.cpp. Check the full build output to see if there are any signs of Dumbbell.cpp and then find and correct the appropriate configuration file. I see VSC as something of a promising work in progress. Right now it takes a fair amount of knowledge to successfully wrangle it.